# Best way to save images and videos using Angular and web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to **`web.api`**. My requirement is to store the image/video into database.

I've three choices:

1. Convert it into base-64 from front end pass it to back end and again convert it into original image and save it in folder.
2. I need to tell front end developer to store it into a folder and give the path of the folder.
3. Some one suggested me to store it in 3rd party servers and take the url.

If you prefer 3rd one, please guide me to follow some steps.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer 3rd one because storing and managing the file on the server will increase the load on the server,  you can save your images and videos on Amazone S3 (https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) server.

Comment: Can you please guide me to follow some steps?

Comment: Following links will helps you
1. Upload a File to an S3 Bucket Using the AWS SDK for .NET https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html
2. S3 desktop application http://s3browser.com/